# How to remove the vboxsf group membership requirement from VirtualBox shared folders?

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I'm automating setup of a virtual machine, where I would like to be able to mount shared folders in VirtualBox and provide all users (including ones already logged on and processes already running) access to it. I know I could add users to the group, but that does not take effect until they start a new process (usually by logging out and back in). It would be convenient to just be able to start using commands from a shared folder or start browsing a newly shared folder right off the bat without requiring adding group membership and restarting or spawning a new process.

I've tried chmod on the shared folder after it's mounted and that also has no effect. How would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the /etc/group file and set the vboxsf group id (GID) number to be one that the users have access to already and the folders that get mounted by virtual box will give immediate access to those users without having to sign on again or spawn a new process. So for example in Ubuntu a currently logged in user can use the Files icon already on the Applications bar to immediately start browsing a newly mounted folder that might otherwise require adding him to the vboxsf group and then logging out and back in or restarting part of the desktop.

NOTE: You cannot do this with groupmod command because it will complain that the GID already exist. You must do it before mounting the folders because the GID from the group file is what will be given the permissions